# equal space between text and button

Tags: html, css

I want to have equal space between text and button, but I am getting unequal space. See the image that I have attached; the red "delete" buttons and the text before that have unequal spaces.

Is there any CSS property that I can use so that the text doesn't push the button to the right?

[image]

```js
function todo() {
  var ParentDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  var newPara = document.createElement('p');
  var value = document.getElementById('input-box').value;
  var newText = document.createTextNode(value);
  var del = document.createElement('input');
  randomId = Math.random();
  // newPara.setAttribute("id",randomId);
  newPara.setAttribute("class", "para");
  del.setAttribute("type", "button");
  del.setAttribute("value", "delete");
  del.setAttribute("onclick", "delt(this)");
  del.setAttribute("class", "delbtn");
  newPara.appendChild(newText);
  newPara.appendChild(del);
  ParentDiv.appendChild(newPara);
}

// function delt(me) {
//     var parentId = me.parentElement.getAttribute("id");
//     //var x = me.parentElement.nodeName;
//     //console.log(parentId);  
//     document.getElementById(parentId).remove();
// }
function delt(me) {
  var parent = me.parentNode;
  var grandParent = parent.parentNode;
  grandParent.removeChild(parent);
  //console.log(grandParent);

}

//delt();
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 25rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 4rem;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#input-box {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

#mybtn {
  background-color: rgb(21, 170, 240);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delbtn {
  background-color: rgb(238, 53, 28);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.para {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>TODO APP</h1>
<input type="text" name="" id="input-box" maxlength="25">
<br><button id="mybtn" onclick="todo();">Add Item</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

[View on GitHub](https://github.com/GMT95/todoApp)

Comment: not clear what your asking for the text is in the middle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to align the text to the left and button to the right.
Below, I've used [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Each `.para` contains a `<span>` for the text and an `<input>` button.
Those two elements are positioned using the flexbox layout, with [`justify-content:space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

```js
function todo() {
  var ParentDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  var newPara = document.createElement('p');
  var value = document.getElementById('input-box').value;
  var newText = document.createElement('span');
  newText.innerHTML = value;
  var del = document.createElement('input');
  randomId = Math.random();
  newPara.setAttribute("class", "para");
  del.setAttribute("type", "button");
  del.setAttribute("value", "delete");
  del.setAttribute("onclick", "delt(this)");
  del.setAttribute("class", "delbtn");
  newPara.appendChild(newText);
  newPara.appendChild(del);
  ParentDiv.appendChild(newPara);
}

function delt(me) {
  var parent = me.parentNode;
  var grandParent = parent.parentNode;
  grandParent.removeChild(parent);
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#input-box {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mybtn {
  background-color: rgb(21, 170, 240);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delbtn {
  background-color: rgb(238, 53, 28);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.para {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.para {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>TODO APP</h1>
  <input type="text" name="" id="input-box" maxlength="25">
  <br><button id="mybtn" onclick="todo();">Add Item</button>
  <div id="mydiv">
    <p class="para">
      <span>Tester</span>
      <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="delt(this)" class="delbtn">
    </p>
    <p class="para">
      <span>Another Test</span>
      <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="delt(this)" class="delbtn">
    </p>
    <p class="para">
      <span>Sample Text</span>
      <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="delt(this)" class="delbtn">
    </p>
    <p class="para">
      <span>Item Title</span>
      <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="delt(this)" class="delbtn">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `<table>` instead of a `<div>` and append the `p` in the left column and the button in the right, so the buttons are always above each other:

```js
function todo() {
  var ParentDiv = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
  var leftCell = document.createElement('td');
  var rightCell = document.createElement('td');
  var newPara = document.createElement('p');
  var value = document.getElementById('input-box').value;
  var newText = document.createTextNode(value);
  var del = document.createElement('input');
  randomId = Math.random();
  // newPara.setAttribute("id",randomId);
  newPara.setAttribute("class", "para");
  del.setAttribute("type", "button");
  del.setAttribute("value", "delete");
  del.setAttribute("onclick", "delt(this)");
  del.setAttribute("class", "delbtn");
  newPara.appendChild(newText);
  rightCell.appendChild(del);
  leftCell.appendChild(newPara);
  newRow.appendChild(leftCell);
  newRow.appendChild(rightCell);
  ParentDiv.appendChild(newRow);
}

// function delt(me) {
//     var parentId = me.parentElement.getAttribute("id");
//     //var x = me.parentElement.nodeName;
//     //console.log(parentId);  
//     document.getElementById(parentId).remove();
// }
function delt(me) {
  var parent = me.parentNode;
  var grandParent = parent.parentNode;
  grandParent.removeChild(parent);
  //console.log(grandParent);

}

//delt();
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 25rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 4rem;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#input-box {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

#mybtn {
  background-color: rgb(21, 170, 240);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delbtn {
  background-color: rgb(238, 53, 28);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.para {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>TODO APP</h1>
<input type="text" name="" id="input-box" maxlength="25">
<br><button id="mybtn" onclick="todo();">Add Item</button>
<table id="mytable"></table>
```